# strapi 4 populate when update

Tags: javascript, strapi

Is there an way to populate the field when updating,

```
...
 const response = await cartService.update(id, { data: { items } });
 const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(response, ctx);
 return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, by attaching the `populate=[your_relational_field]` as the `query string` in the http `PUT` request call.

###### Sample request

`http://localhost:1337/api/cart/2?populate=category`

###### Sample request body in JSON format

```json
{
   "data": {
        "items": "items data here"
   }
}
```

**That's all!** You don't even need to override the core update method in your controller and the query string will directly be picked up by `StrapiV4`. But in case for some reason you've overridden the core `update` method from the controller, then you can simply pass the `ctx` instance to the core `update` or `findOne` methods like below:

```js
"use strict";

/**
 *  cart controller
 */
const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::cart.cart", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async update(ctx) {
    // let's say you've written some custom logic here
    // finally return the response from core update method
    const response = await super.update(ctx);
    return response;

    // OR
    // You can even use the core `findOne` method instead
    const response = await super.findOne(ctx);
    return response;

    // OR
    // if you've used some other service then you can pass in the populate option to the update method
    const response = await cartService.update(id, {data: { items }, populate: "items.product" });
    return response;
  },
}));
```

Comment: I have to update using this "cartService.update(id, { data: { items } })", because I have some logic before, is there any way to pass populate options to update() function instead of "ctx"

Comment: it worked i just passed:   update(id, {data: { items },populate: "items.product",}); , Thanks

Comment: Cool, I'll just append it to the answer so that it may also help others in future.